# Flutter: Remove leading zeros from time format

Tags: flutter, dart, time-format

I am receiving a string in this format `'HH:mm:ss'` and I need to get rid of the leading zeros OR convert it to minutes/hours. Is there a `RegExp` to achieve this?

Examples with no leading zeros:

```
00:03:15 => 3:15
10:10:10 => 10:10:10
00:00:00 => 0:00
04:00:00 => 4:00:00
00:42:32 => 42:32
00:00:18 => 0:18
00:00:08 => 0:08
```

Examples of time converted to minutes/hours

```
00:07:00 => 7 min
00:10:30 => 10:30 min
01:40:00 => 1h 40 min
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following

Add intl package to your pubspec.yaml file.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("HH:mm");
```

Converting DateTime object to String

```
DateTime yourDate = DateTime.now());
String string = dateFormat.format(yourDate);
```

Can also try this

```
DateTime yourDate = DateTime.now();
String string =  new DateFormat.Hm().format(yourDate);    // force 24 hour time
```

### Update

To Parse a String to a Date you can use this

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat('HH:mm:ss');
DateTime dt = df.parse('00:07:00');
String string = DateFormat.Hm().format(dt);
```

References

- [DateFormat Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Comment: ```DateTime yourDate = DateTime.now();``` - I am receiving a string (00:07:00) and it can't be assigned to the type DateTime. Is there a way to convert a string to DateTime? Then I could format it the way I need. Thanks

Comment: @selected i have edited my answer to parse your value to the DateTime object

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Comment: Note that `DateFormat("HH:mm");` still gives you time like `07:51` with a leading zero. To get `7:51`, use `DateFormat("H:mm");`.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like at this point just using a single char (eg, `M` instead of `MM`) in the format string handles the trim of leading zeroes:

**BEFORE:**

```
// Output: 01/01/2021, 02:41 PM
static final dateFormatLeadingZeros = new DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a');
```

**AFTER:**

```
// Output: 1/1/2021, 2:41 PM
static final dateFormatTrimmed = new DateFormat('M/d/yyyy, h:mm a');
```